# Comparing two arrays while counting number of correct and incorrect answers

Tags: c#, arrays

I wrote a program where the user plays a game and guesses answers.
Everything works good except my arrays, the program has two arrays, the first one is usersAnswers which contains the users choices and the second one called decompTimeArray which contains the correct answers. I wrote a method where the program will compare both arrays and count how many answers the users got right and wrong and place their values in two separate labels. The program runs fine but it always gives me 0 for both correct and incorrect labels, i would appreciate if you help me out in fixing this small issue and make the program count the answers properly. Here's my code:

```
public void usersAnswers()
    {


        userAnswers[0] = newspaperLbl.Text;
        userAnswers[1] = aluminumCanLbl.Text;
        userAnswers[2] = glassBottleLbl.Text;
        userAnswers[3] = plasticbagLbl.Text;
        userAnswers[4] = cupLbl.Text;
    }

    public void correctAnswers()
    {

        decompTimeArray[0] = "6 Weeks";
        decompTimeArray[1] = "10-20 Years";
        decompTimeArray[2] = "80-200 Years";
        decompTimeArray[3] = "1,000,000 Years";
        decompTimeArray[4] = "Never";
    }

    public void compareArrays()
    {
        bool arraysEqual = true;
        int index;
        if (userAnswers.Length != decompTimeArray.Length)
        {
            arraysEqual = false;

        }

        for (index = 0; index < userAnswers.Length; index++)
        {
            if (decompTimeArray[index] != userAnswers[index])
            {
                arraysEqual = false;
                wrong++;

            }
            else
            {
                arraysEqual = false;
                right++;

            }
            /*This part of the program will compare the arrays from 
             * methods 1,2 we use a for loop*/

        }

        if (arraysEqual)
        {
            Results Result = new Results();
            Result.correctAnswersLbl.Text = right.ToString("n");


        }
        else
        {
            Results Result = new Results();
            Result.incorrectAnswersLbl.Text = wrong.ToString("n");


        }
    }

    public void checkAnswersBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Results Result = new Results();
        Result.userAnswer1Label.Text = newspaperLbl.Text;
        Result.userAnswer2Label.Text = aluminumCanLbl.Text;
        Result.userAnswer3Label.Text = glassBottleLbl.Text;
        Result.userAnswer4Label.Text = plasticbagLbl.Text;
        Result.userAnswer5Label.Text = cupLbl.Text;
        Result.correctAnswersLbl.Text = right.ToString("n");
        Result.incorrectAnswersLbl.Text = wrong.ToString("n");
        percentage = (wrong / 5) * 100;
        Result.percentageLbl.Text = percentage.ToString("p");
        this.Hide();
        Introduction Intro = new Introduction();
        Intro.Hide();
        Result.ShowDialog();






    }
}
```

}

Comment: Consider debugging code. Side note: duplicated data is alway pain in the ###. You really don't need incorrectly computed `arraysEqual` variable - in normal case `right+wrong` should be length of the array...

Answer (score 0):

If `wrong` is an `integer`, you are doing an integer division here : `percentage = (wrong / 5) * 100;`

So if wrong is `4`, for example, you will get `4/5 = 0 * 100 = 0`. So you'll always display `0`.

You need to either convert wrong to a `double` (or `decimal` or `float`), or the value 5 itself (which is preferable, since you can't really get 'partial' answers) by rewriting it `5.0`.

So

```
percentage = (int)((wrong / 5.0) * 100);
                            ^
                            |
      This will be a double-|
```

will trigger the correct division type; the operation will now be calculated as `4 / 5.0 = 0.8*100 = 80`